# OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam, opengl

So the title is pretty self explanatory about my problem. I went on vacation a couple weeks ago, everything was fine and now, two weeks later, I get back, no one has touched the computer and this happens...

Here is the output from the terminal for openGL GLX:

```
    exos9@Sentar ~ $ glxinfo
    name of display: :0.0
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
    And so on for a few hundred lines...
```

Does anyone know how I might solve this or what might cause it?